# Automator to open random file on Windows share

Tags: network, finder, applescript, automator

I have created through automator the ability to locally open a random file in a specified folder with subfolders.  I cannot figure out how to do this on a networked Windows share.

I have:

1. Get Specified Servers = `smb://Share/Folder 1`
2. Connect to Servers = it connects
3. Run AppleScript

   ```
   tell application "Finder"

       set location to :: -- NOT WORKING!

       set randomFolder to some folder in folder "location"
       open some file in randomFolder
   end tell
   ```

Any thoughts to what the syntax is for location? Or am I missing the mark completely with these actions? I have tried several variations and nothing works.

Note: there is a space in the location "Folder 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **Automator** *workflow* works for me:

[image: Example Automator workflow]

---

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set thisFolder to (item 1 of input as string)

    tell application "Finder"
        set randomFolder to some folder in folder thisFolder
        open some file in randomFolder
    end tell

end run
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate/needed/wanted. The onus is upon the user to add any appropriate error handling as may be appropriate/needed/wanted.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. This was extremely helpful!